# Node.js/Mongoose: Send info to a function and recognize the info to operate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, operation

I have an app that makes requests to 3 different API REST servers, gather and manipulate the info received into objects and uses mongoose's model to send the info different Mongo collections (one for each API REST).

My objective is to have a function operate on the different sets of info right before or at the same time (or right after) it is sent to the MongoDB.

Here's an example with 2 concrete objects that are being retrieved and sent to the db:

Object1:

```
{
   "name": "X",
   "a": 10,
   "b": 9,
   "n": 1502642712481,
   "iname": "ix",
   "_id": "59907f34040eb562d8d11d8c"
}
```

Object2:

```
{
   "name": "Y",
   "n": 1502642712552,
   "iname": "ix",
   "_id": "59907f34040eb562d8d11d8d",
   "b": "10",
   "a": "9",
}
```

These have their own models and are correctly being inserted into the MongoDB with a save and I want to compare the "a" and "b" keys of each objects (FYI: `"iname"` is a common key for both objects and `"n"` is a timestamp created at the moment the request is being returned).
The type of operation I want to make on `'a'` and `'b'` are relatively basic mathematics (at the moment): `ax - ay` and `bx -by`

Any idea on how I could do that ?

Right now the code to save each object to the db are nested within an infinite loop and looks like:

```
async function loopY() {
  setTimeout(
    async function () {
      var list = ['Y']; 
      var data = await y(list); //<---- This is the call to wait whatever the request of Y will return
          data.forEach((object) => {
            if (object.name === 'Y') {
              var iname =  'ix'
            } else {
              var iname = 'N/A' };
            var tick = new Ymodel({
              mk: object.mk,
              name: object.name,
              a: object.a,
              b: object.b,
              n: object.n,
              iname: iname,
            });
            // tick.sendToCompare(); //<---- HERE I THOUGHT OF USING A FUNCTION FROM THE MODEL BUT NOT SURE HOW TO HANDLE THE DIVISION BETWEEN THE INFORMATION
            tick.save(function(err, tick) {
              if (err) return console.log(err);
              console.log(`[SUCCESS]: ${tick.name} added to db!`);
            });
          });
          loopY();
        }
  }, 1000); // <------- THE TIMEOUT HELPS ME MANAGE THE REQUESTS TO THE API SERVERS AND AVOID A "TOO MANY REQUESTS" ERROR.
};

loopY();
```

I have the exact same function for `"X"` (`loopX()`) with the slight difference that it adds an `"sn"` key to the object.

I hope this was clear enough and respected the rules... Also, thanks a lot in advance for your help!